# Use batch file to lookup text in CSV & parse it in to run an application install

Tags: csv, powershell, batch-file

I have an application that is to be deployed to 1000+ Windows machines. Each machine is in a remote office and is given a Node ID 1-35 and a Branch ID eg. 001122 (unique to each office). I have the install running silently but at one point it asks you to enter the Node ID and Branch ID. I am using the below code in a batch file to allow the engineer running the install to enter the details manually but this is very time consuming and we would prefer to have no user interaction.

We have all the hostnames, IPs, Node ID and Branch ID in one CSV.

My question is, is it possible for the bat file (or another scripting language) to check the IP address or hostname of the pc locate this in the CSV and to parse in the Node ID and Branch ID found in the corresponding rows. How might I go about changing set /p to look at a csv. I am not a coder so am unsure of how to go about reading in a CSV.

Sample of batch file used:

```batch
@echo off

setlocal

(set /p NodeId=Enter Node ID:)
(set /p GroupId=Enter Branch ID:)

:: Check that parameter is passed in
if %GroupId%.==. echo WS Group Id required as parameter & GoTo :END
if %NodeId%.==. echo WS Node Id required as parameter & GoTo :END
if %NodeId% GTR 31 echo WS Node Id should be less than 32 & GoTo :END

set GroupId=%GroupId%
set NodeId=%NodeId%

echo Installing Workstation Group=%GroupId% and Node=%NodeId%
```

Comment: " I am not a coder so am unsure of how to go about reading in a csv." Perhaps you should go and hire a programmer. We are not a free coding service.

Comment: Drop batch and use [PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849891.aspx).

Comment: David the question -  is it possible  does not mean please give me the code. Im trying to first find out if it can be done if someone suggested using a parameter other than Set Ill be happy to research that.

Comment: if `hostname` is equal to %computername%` then it should be easy. See `for /?` how to parse a file (or a line, you found with `find /?` or `findstr /?`

Comment: Thanks stephen, The hostname is %computername%.
I didn't know about these command they look exactly like what I need. I'm also going to try out Import-Csv in Powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a CSV like the following:

```
Hostname,IP,NodeID,BranchID
Chef,192.168.0.10,1-35,001122
Secretary,192.168.0.12,1-38,001122
Test,192.168.0.24,1-40,00112
...
```

this should work:

```
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%a in ('type file.csv ^|find /i "%computername%" ') do (
  echo Installing Workstation %%a, Group=%%d, Node=%%c with Address %%b
  set groupID=%%d
  set nodeID=%%c
)
```

Comment: Please show your output (and ideally (part of) your `csv` file).

Comment: Sorry hadn't finished the last comment and hit enter by mistake.

@Stephan thanks for that. I tried but it does not seem to be setting the parameters. Am I placing this in the wrong section.
The csv is been readin ok 
Installing Workstation ---------- COMPUTERS.CSV, Group=, Node= with Address
Installing Workstation PTSBBRANCH, Group=990610, Node=14 with Address 10.250.58.
14

Comment: '@echo off

setlocal

for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%a in ('find /i "%computername%" computers.csv') do (
  echo Installing Workstation %%a, Group=%%d, Node=%%c with Address %%b
)

:: Check that parameter is passed in
if %GroupId%.==. echo WS Group Id required as parameter & GoTo :END
if %NodeId%.==. echo WS Node Id required as parameter & GoTo :END
if %NodeId% GTR 31 echo WS Node Id should be less than 32 & GoTo :END'

Comment: set GroupId=%GroupId%
    set NodeId=%NodeId%'

    echo Installing Workstation Group=%GroupId% and Node=%NodeId%'

    When I run the batch I get this.

    'Installing Workstation Group= and Node=